# Execute pipeline if specific piece of config is changed

Tags: bash, aws-cli, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to execute bitbucket pipeline only if specific piece of config in yml file is changed. For example, we have this piece of config in config.yml

```
someKey:
  value: string
anotherKey:
  anothervalue: number
hdp:
  version: 1.0.0
```

and I want to execute aws cli within bitbucket pipeline only if that version number is modified in commit, nothing else. Something like

```
if version value is modified in commit
then
  some aws cli
  exit 0
else
  echo "no relevant changes pushed"
  exit 1
fi
```

I know it's not possible to achieve it by bitbucket pipeline configuration itself, but is there some way how to check in bash if commit contains changes to specific string/line? It's yaml so maybe is there way how to check if value was changed for key?
To be clear. I don't want to run pipeline if anything in config is changed. I want to run it, only of version is changed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, I didn't realize repo is automatically cloned into docker image once Bitbucket pipeline is started. All I had to do was install git. Then I was able to do git show > commit.txt and then grep on commit.txt and find whatever I need.